# Feeder value not updated in gatling test

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

### I am new to scala and gatling . I am trying to fetch values from feeder and post zip file to service . but ${extensionId} is not been updated with fetched value instead it remain as ${extensionId} . Could some one please help me know If I miss some thing here .

```
          def installExtension() =
            exec(http("template - Install Extension")
              .post(url + "/v1/extensions")
              .basicAuth("jack", "password")
              .headers(namespaceHeader)
// using testUtils to get InputStream conte
              .body(InputStreamBody(TestUtils.toStream(hashMap.get("${extensionId}").getOrElse(null))))
              .check(status.is( 201)))


 class extmgrSimulations extends Simulation {

          val extensionIds = csv(s"${Configuration.dataDirectory}/extensionId.csv").circular


          val extMgrScenerio = scenario("extensionMgr - Scenario")
            .during(Configuration.duration) {
              exitBlockOnFail(
                group("load-test") {
                  exec(
                    pace(Configuration.paceFrom, Configuration.paceTo),
                    feed(extensionIds),feed(extensionIds)
                      randomSwitch(
                      50.00 -> group("Install and delete") {
                        exec(
                          extmgrChain.installExtension(),
                          extmgrChain.deleteExtension(),
                        )
                      },
                      50.00 -> extmgrChain.listExtension()
                    )
                  )
                }
              )
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't work. Gatling EL (the ${} syntax in strings) doesn't magically work anywhere. This is explained in the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/#expression-language).

> Warning
>
> This Expression Language only works on String values being passed to Gatling DSL methods. Such Strings are parsed only once, when the Gatling simulation is being instantiated.
>
> For example queryParam("latitude", session => "${latitude}") wouldn’t work because the parameter is not a String, but a function that returns a String.
>
> Also, queryParam("latitude", "${latitude}".toInt) wouldn’t because the toInt would happen before passing the parameter to the queryParam method.
>
> The solution here would be to pass a function:
>
> session => session("latitude").validate[Int].